# calculate unit in stock of a product

Tags: mysql

This is the question:

> To find
> units in stock of a product, use the InventoryTransactions table, find total quantity
> purchased and subtract quantities sold and on hold.

The Inventory Transaction table:

[image]

This are the transaction type for each transaction id:

**transaction id 1 = purchased, trasaction id 2 = sold, transaction id 3 = on hold**

```
+----+-----------+
| ID | TypeName  |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Purchased |
|  2 | Sold      |
|  3 | On Hold   |
|  4 | Waste     |
+----+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The product id, quantity, and type of transaction:

```
SELECT productid, quantity, transactiontype FROM Inventory_Transactions ORDER BY productid;

+-----------+----------+-----------------+
| productid | quantity | transactiontype |
+-----------+----------+-----------------+
|         1 |       40 |               1 |
|         1 |       15 |               2 |
|         1 |       25 |               3 |
|         3 |      100 |               1 |
|         3 |       50 |               2 |
|         4 |       40 |               1 |
|         4 |       10 |               2 |
|         4 |       30 |               2 |
|         5 |       40 |               1 |
|         5 |       25 |               2 |
|         6 |      100 |               1 |
|         6 |       10 |               2 |
|         6 |       90 |               2 |
|         7 |       40 |               1 |
|         7 |       10 |               2 |
|         7 |       30 |               2 |
|         8 |       40 |               1 |
|         8 |       17 |               2 |
|         8 |       25 |               1 |
|         8 |       25 |               2 |
|         8 |       20 |               2 |
|         8 |        3 |               2 |
|        14 |       40 |               1 |
|        17 |       40 |               1 |
|        17 |       40 |               2 |
|        19 |       20 |               1 |
|        19 |       20 |               2 |
|        19 |       30 |               1 |
|        19 |       30 |               2 |
|        19 |       25 |               1 |
|        19 |       10 |               2 |
|        19 |       10 |               1 |
|        19 |       25 |               2 |
|        20 |       40 |               1 |
|        20 |       40 |               2 |
|        21 |       20 |               1 |
|        21 |       20 |               2 |
|        34 |       60 |               1 |
|        34 |      100 |               1 |
|        34 |      100 |               2 |
|        34 |       12 |               3 |
|        34 |       10 |               3 |
|        34 |        1 |               3 |
|        34 |       50 |               1 |
|        34 |      300 |               1 |
|        34 |      300 |               2 |
|        34 |       87 |               2 |
|        40 |      120 |               1 |
|        40 |       50 |               2 |
|        40 |       30 |               2 |
|        40 |       40 |               2 |
|        41 |       40 |               1 |
|        41 |      200 |               1 |
|        41 |      200 |               2 |
|        41 |       30 |               2 |
|        41 |       50 |               1 |
|        41 |       50 |               2 |
|        41 |       10 |               2 |
|        43 |      100 |               1 |
|        43 |       20 |               2 |
|        43 |      300 |               1 |
|        43 |      300 |               2 |
|        43 |       25 |               3 |
|        43 |      250 |               1 |
|        43 |      300 |               3 |
|        43 |        5 |               2 |
|        48 |      100 |               1 |
|        48 |       10 |               2 |
|        48 |      100 |               1 |
|        48 |      100 |               2 |
|        48 |       10 |               2 |
|        48 |       40 |               2 |
|        48 |       40 |               2 |
|        51 |       40 |               1 |
|        51 |       10 |               2 |
|        51 |       30 |               2 |
|        52 |      100 |               1 |
|        52 |       40 |               2 |
|        56 |      120 |               1 |
|        56 |      110 |               3 |
|        57 |       80 |               1 |
|        57 |      100 |               1 |
|        57 |      100 |               2 |
|        65 |       40 |               1 |
|        66 |       80 |               1 |
|        72 |       40 |               1 |
|        72 |       50 |               1 |
|        72 |       50 |               2 |
|        72 |       40 |               2 |
|        74 |       20 |               1 |
|        74 |       20 |               2 |
|        77 |       60 |               1 |
|        80 |       75 |               1 |
|        80 |       30 |               2 |
|        80 |       10 |               2 |
|        80 |       20 |               3 |
|        80 |       15 |               2 |
|        81 |      125 |               1 |
|        81 |      200 |               1 |
|        81 |      200 |               2 |
|        81 |       50 |               3 |
|        81 |       25 |               3 |
+-----------+----------+-----------------+
102 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I will need to calculate unit of stock for each productid by **SUM(quantity purchased) - SUM(quantity sold) - SUM(quantity on hold)**

My take:

```
CREATE VIEW purchased AS 
SELECT productid, SUM(quantity) quantity 
FROM Inventory_Transactions 
WHERE transactiontype = 1 
GROUP BY productid 
ORDER BY productid;

CREATE VIEW sold AS 
SELECT productid, SUM(quantity) quantity 
FROM Inventory_Transactions 
WHERE transactiontype = 2 
GROUP BY productid 
ORDER BY productid;

CREATE VIEW onhold AS 
SELECT productid, SUM(quantity) quantity 
FROM Inventory_Transactions 
WHERE transactiontype = 3 
GROUP BY productid 
ORDER BY productid;

SELECT pur.productid, pur.quantity - so.quantity - on.quantity 
FROM purchased pur, sold so, onhold on 
WHERE pur.productid = so.productid = on.productid;
```

But I got this error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on WHERE pur.productid = so.productid = on.productid' at line 1
```

These are the individual VIEW I created above:

```
SELECT * FROM purchased;
+-----------+----------+
| productid | quantity |
+-----------+----------+
|         1 |       40 |
|         3 |      100 |
|         4 |       40 |
|         5 |       40 |
|         6 |      100 |
|         7 |       40 |
|         8 |       65 |
|        14 |       40 |
|        17 |       40 |
|        19 |       85 |
|        20 |       40 |
|        21 |       20 |
|        34 |      510 |
|        40 |      120 |
|        41 |      290 |
|        43 |      650 |
|        48 |      200 |
|        51 |       40 |
|        52 |      100 |
|        56 |      120 |
|        57 |      180 |
|        65 |       40 |
|        66 |       80 |
|        72 |       90 |
|        74 |       20 |
|        77 |       60 |
|        80 |       75 |
|        81 |      325 |
+-----------+----------+
28 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

```
SELECT * FROM sold;
+-----------+----------+
| productid | quantity |
+-----------+----------+
|         1 |       15 |
|         3 |       50 |
|         4 |       40 |
|         5 |       25 |
|         6 |      100 |
|         7 |       40 |
|         8 |       65 |
|        17 |       40 |
|        19 |       85 |
|        20 |       40 |
|        21 |       20 |
|        34 |      487 |
|        40 |      120 |
|        41 |      290 |
|        43 |      325 |
|        48 |      200 |
|        51 |       40 |
|        52 |       40 |
|        57 |      100 |
|        72 |       90 |
|        74 |       20 |
|        80 |       55 |
|        81 |      200 |
+-----------+----------+
23 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

```
SELECT * FROM onhold;
+-----------+----------+
| productid | quantity |
+-----------+----------+
|         1 |       25 |
|        34 |       23 |
|        43 |      325 |
|        56 |      110 |
|        80 |       20 |
|        81 |       75 |
+-----------+----------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I am using the northwind database

Here are all the table relationship in northwind database.
[image]
May I know how do I solve this?

Comment: MySQL or SQL? You have to decide...

Comment: Sorry, its MySQL

Comment: it's likely not mySQL if you're using a northwind database: it's MS SQL Server.  unless you imported MS SQL Server's northwind database...  However, that's irrelevant to the question as what you're doing is pretty database agnostic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I would take is using something called "Conditional aggregation"

- use a summed case expression to determine if it's a purchase
- use a summed 2nd case expression to determine if it's a sale/hold
- subtract the two
- group by product

.

```
SELECT ProductID,
   SUM(case when TransactionType = 1 then quantity else 0 end) - 
   SUM(case when TransactionType in (2,3) then quantity else 0 end) as AvailableInventory
FROM Inventory_Transactions
GROUP BY ProductID
```

As to the nature of your error:
`you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on WHERE pur.productid = so.productid = on.productid' at line 1`

1. `on` is a reserved word use onh or onhold or something for the alias
2. using `,` joins is and old technique use Inner, outer, full outer, cross join and use the `on` notation to specify how he tables relate
3. equality checks within where clauses must return true false.  To date they are not trinary.  If A=B but <> C what would you expect to happen?  so break out your productID's so they handle all the needed joins.
4. you're going to have problems of matching records because not all 3 may have a value so if you match on productID for sold or hold, you may not have a product and it would fall out of your results... thus outer joins are needed if you continue with your current approach.

.

ORIGINAL

```
SELECT pur.productid, pur.quantity - so.quantity - on.quantity 
FROM purchased pur, sold so, onhold on 
WHERE pur.productid = so.productid = on.productid;
```

should be:

```
SELECT coalesce(pur.productid, so.productid,onhold.ProductID) as productid,  
       coalesce(pur.quantity,0) - coalesce(so.quantity,0) - 
       coalesce(onhold.quantity) as AvailableInventory
FROM purchased pur
FULL OUTER JOIN sold so
   on pur.productid = so.productid 
FULL OUTER JOIN onhold 
   on pur.productid = onhold.productid
   OR so.productid = onhold.productid
GROUP BY coalesce(pur.productid, so.productid,onhold.ProductID);
```

Breaking this down

- the coalesce of productID is because we don't know in which of the 1,2,3 a productID will exist.  But, we need the product id to show up for any of the 3 not just purchases.
- the coalesce on quantity is because if we try to subtract a NULL value, we get a NULL so we need to ensure a numeric value exists.  pretend for a second product ID 1 exists in purchases but has had no sales or holds.  10 purchases - NULL = NULL... not what we want.  now if the productID 2 is in sales but not purchases we'd have NULL-10-NULL... again not what we want.  Also if we just used the productid from purchases it would be NULL on this record...; also not good.
- we replaced the `,` notation which is a cross join to a `full outer` so we don't lose records.  Now cross join would work but it takes # of purchases * #of sales * number of on hold then limits the records based on your where clause this is WAY more work than the database needs to do and on a large dataset would be VERY slow.
- Discussed earlier, where clause can't be trinary it must be a binary result comparing just 2 values.

Now `full outer` vs `left` vs `inner` vs `right`....

- FULL OUTER: include all records from both tables and line them up where they match on Key (productID in our example)
- LEFT JOIN include all records from the first table and any that match from the 2nd
- INNER Include only records which exist in both tables.
- RIGHT include all records from the 2nd table and any that match from the 1st.
- CROSS JOIN: all records related to all records (Very slow but there are uses; just not here)
- and more...

If we can't assume each of your products has a value in each group: pur, sold, onhold; we need to use full outer joins as above; so we don't exclude any records. However even this can be an issue because we have to ensure each productID ties back to a related product in another table if it exists.
To do this we have to use an OR on the last match (kinda ugly)  and as we don't know the source of productID... we have to find one using coalesce.

If we can assume all products must first exist as a purchase, we can left join the other two. A bit cleaner, but we still have to handle the situation where there may be no data in sold or on hold, so we have to coalesce the 0 in for the quantities.  we don't have to coalesce the productid since we know a purchase has to exist.

```
SELECT pur.productid, sum(coalesce(pur.quantity,0) - coalesce(so.quantity,0) - 
   coalesce(onhold.quantity)) as AvailableInventory
FROM purchased pur
LEFT OUTER JOIN sold so
   on pur.productid = so.productid 
LEFT OUTER JOIN onhold 
   on pur.productid = onhold.productid
   --Note: we tie back to pur both times as we know it exists there.
GROUP BY pur.productid;
```

Hopefully you can see the conditional aggregation is the better approach as it simplifies and reduces joins and avoids much of the coalesing we do.

Comment: Expecting a TLDR here but hopefully it covers the need.

Comment: updated from TransactionID to TransactionType when evaluting the type of transaction (Pur,Sal,OnHhold)  occurs to me transactionID is nto the same as TransactionType.